# 'ls' command not working on mac OS Catalina

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash

Ever since updating my mac to OS Catalina I have noticed quite a few changes were made to the terminal.

Upon opening the terminal there is always the entry:

```
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
```

I've noticed that when using `ls`,  instead of listing the items within the current directory, it activated ghostscript. In a flurry of frustration I uninstalled ghostscript using the opensource script from https://gist.github.com/gwerbin/dcba755b0484423e9e45.

Now when I run `ls`, I get the following output:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.16: Can't find initialization file gs_init.ps.
```

How do I repair things, so that I can get `ls` or at least have a new command `dir` that lists the directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to change your shell from `bash` to `zsh`, then add this to your `.bashrc` file:

```
export BASH_SILENCE_DEPRECATION_WARNING=1
```

To edit this you can use this command:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

While you are editing your `.bashrc` file, look for aliases or functions which redefined `ls` use Ghostscript.

Try `which -a ls` in Terminal.app to show you what `ls` is currently defined as, and what other `ls` commands are available.

Comment: Thanks for the `which` tip, I see that there is another program tagged to `ls` under `/usr/local/bin/ls` which is the alias to ghostscript. I tried looking for `~/.bashrc` however was unable to find it

Comment: @tian see the edit

Comment: You can create a `~/.bashrc` file if it doesn’t exist. I think bash might also use `~/.profile`. You should be able to delete the `/usr/local/bin/ls` if Ghostscript is uninstalled.

Comment: How do I remove the alias for Ghostscript if I cannot find it in the `~/.bashrc` & `~/.profile`?

Comment: @Tian You’ve already asked two questions here. Why not ask a follow up question stating you found this program and how to remove it? You can link the second question to here if needed. Be sure to vote up and accept TJ’s answer. you got two solid answers already from this

Comment: @bmike I don't think the question was answered, I still face the same issue because  there does not exist those two files for me to remove the alias. How to remove the depreciation warning was not the solution, my original mentioning of Ghostscript depreciation was to elaborate on my main issue

Comment: You don't need to remove a bash alias, you need to remove the file `/usr/local/bin/ls` (or rename it, if you want to keep it). So do that, at @TJLuoma said.